# Bag of Marbles problem from exercises for feynman lectures

Tags: probability

You have 100 marbles numbered 0 to 99 in a bag. You repeatedly draw a marble from the bag (all marbles being equiprobable), note its number, and replace it in the bag. On average, how many of the marbles numbered 1 through 99 will have been drawn from the bag one or more timesbefore drawing marble #0?

This is a problem from exercises for feynman lectures.

I have tried to solve this problem. First i found the probability of the occurance of an $n$ length sequence excluding the terminating zero. which results in $$\frac{99^n}{100^{n+1}}$$  then i found the probability that this $n$ length sequence containing only $k$ unique numbers from $1 to 99$. Which i got as $$\frac{99C_k *k^{n-k}}{100^n}$$. Then the joined combination is summed over $k from 1 to 99 & n from 1 to Infinity$. But i couldn't get the correct answer which is $\frac{99}{2}$
Please tell me where i went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A far simpler approach:

For each $i\in \{1,2,\dots,99\}$ let $X_i$ be the indicator random variable equal to $1$ if at least one marble numbered $i$ was drawn before any marble numbered $0$, and equal to $0$ otherwise.

It is easy to show that $Pr(X_i=1)=Pr(X_i=0)=\frac{1}{2}$, due to the symmetry of the problem.  Search elsewhere on this site for a formal proof if you are unconvinced.

As $X_i$ is an indicator randomvariable it follows that $E[X_i]=Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{2}$

Now, recognize that the total number of marble id's which have been seen before a $0$ is drawn is $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{99}X_i$ and by the linearity of expectation you have:

$$E[X]=E[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{99}X_i]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{99}E[X_i] = 99\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

---

As for your mistake... it appears as though you are asserting that the probability of exactly $k$ different numbers appearing in $n$ pulls given that the $n+1$'st pull is $0$ as being $\dfrac{\binom{99}{k} k^{n-k}}{100^n}$.  I assume that your logic went something like "*we'll first choose which $k$ of the numbers were seen, then we'll guarantee an occurrence of each, then for the rest of the pulls we let them be any from the list of selected numbers*"

This is a good idea, but implemented incorrectly.  The probability you found was in actuality the probability that exactly $k$ values were seen, and *very specifically* within the first $k$ pulls *the $k$ values all appear exactly once each in increasing order* after which you have the remaining pulls all being any from the list of selected values.  This however does not account for situations where you repeat any value within the first $k$ pulls nor does it account for situations where the $k$ values first appear in an order other than increasing order.

To correct your approach, you should look into using [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), however this is overly complicated compared to the argument above using the linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to go wrong when you calculate the expected number of chosen marbles from 1-99 when you choose $n$ of them with replacement. It's easier to calculate the expected number of unchosen marbles in this situation, so I'll do that instead.

If I choose $n$ marbles numbered $1$ to $N-1$, the probability of an individual marble being unchosen is $[(N-2)/(N-1)]^k$. That is, the probability that with each choice, a different marble was chosen. So if we look at a single marble, the expected number of unchosen marbles is $[(N-2)/(N-1)]^n$. By linearity of expectation, the expected number of unchosen marbles for all $N-1$ of them is $E_n = (N-1)[(N-2)/(N-1)]^n$.

Now, you've already found that the probability distribution of the number of marbles $n$ chosen before the one numbered $0$ is $P(n) = (N-1)^n/N^{n+1}$. So the expected number of unchosen marbles is
\begin{multline}
E = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(n)E_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(N-1)^n(N-1)(N-2)^n}{N^{n+1}(N-1)^n} = \frac{N-1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{N-2}{N}\right)^n \\= \frac{N-1}{N}\left(1 - \frac{N-2}{N}\right)^{-1} = \frac{N-1}{2}
\end{multline}
Since there are $N-1$ marbles not numbered $0$, the expected number of those marbles chosen at least once is also $(N-1)/2$. In this case, $N = 100$, so the expected number is $99/2$.

Comment: Is there a difference between probability and expected number?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on a bit more on how linearity of expectation is applied here?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the symmetry argument at all, but I find this problem relatively easy to do with conditional probabilities:

Let ${X_i}$ be a Bernoulli random variable indicating whether marble ${i\in[1,99]}$ occurred before marble ${0}$. Further let ${N}$ be a random variable denoting where in the sequence the marble ${0}$ was drawn for the first time. Then, ${P(X_i=0 | N=n )}$ is the probability that marble ${i}$ is not drawn before marble ${0}$ given marble zero was drawn on the ${n}$-th draw.

For each marble, ${i}$, the conditional probability is ${P(X_i=0 | N=n )=(\frac{98}{99})^{n-1}}$. This is because, given marble ${0}$ isn't drawn until the ${n}$-th draw, the ${n-1}$ preceding marbles can only be one of the ${99}$ other marbles. But since we're interested in ${X_i=0}$, we're only interested in the subset where none of them are ${i}$ either.

By similar reasoning, it's easy to see that ${P(N=n) = (\frac{99}{100})^{n-1}\frac{1}{100}}$.

By the law of total probability, ${P(X_i=0) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X_i=0 | N=n)P(N=n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{98}{99})^{n-1}(\frac{99}{100})^{n-1}\frac{1}{100} = \frac{1}{2}}$.

Finally, ${P(X_i=1) = 1-P(X_i=0)=\frac{1}{2}}$.

Now let ${M = \sum_{i=1}^{99}X_i}$. Then ${E(M)=\sum_{i=1}^{99}E(X_i)=\frac{99}{2}}$.

(Note that this doesn't require that ${X_i}$ are independent so M is not necessarily a Binomial distribution).